# SUM From Sheet 1 Columns to Sheet 2 Rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Tried searching for a while, didn't see what I was looking for.

On Sheet1, I have approximately 100 columns, each representing an item.  Each row is populated by a quantity of that item.  As you can imagine, it's very annoying to scroll right continuously, so I created Sheet2 ("Quantities").  In this sheet, I created the same headers as sheet1, except, instead of each item having a column, i made each item a row.  So, for example:

Sheet1:

```
A1:I1 contains customer information.  No calculating needs to be done here.
J1:DG1 contains a bunch of items (fish, salad, etc).
J2 contains quantity of fish that was ordered by customer A2.
J3 contains quantity of fish that was ordered by customer A3.
K2 contains quantity of salad that was ordered by customer A2.
K3 contains quantity of salad that was ordered by customer A3.
```

Sheet2:

```
A1:A102 contains same information as J1:DG1.
```

Understood so far? Great. :)

In Sheet2, I would like `B1:B102` to equal the `SUM` of its equivalent in Sheet1.  So, for example, B1 in Sheet2 would be: `=SUM(Sheet1!J2:J1048576)` (sum of entire column J). That works great.  The issue is, how do I copy that formula so that it populates `B2:B102`.  If I copy what I wrote above is in B1, I get an error.  It DOES work, if I try to copy B1's forumula to `C1:DG1`, but that defeats the purpose, I need it to paste downwards.  (transpose doesn't work either).

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround.
[2nd post](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/transposing-cells-which-contains-formula-t2946068.html) in linked thread.  ([Mirror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWZwv.jpg))

As I mentioned in OP, if I tried making `Sheet2 B1 =SUM(Sheet!J:J)`, and then copy that *to the right, across columns*, it would properly continue the formula to match `C1 =SUM(Sheet1!K:K), D1 =SUM(Sheet1!L:L, etc`).  The problem was, however, that if tried to copy the formula *downwards*, across rows, it would improperly handle the formula.  The problem occurred even if I first copied to the right, across columns, and then `cut/paste-special-transpose`.  Thanks to the workaround though, I was able to fix the transpose problem, and get all cells in `Sheet2 B:B` to represent a `SUM` from `Sheet1`.

Good luck!

Edit:
Adding mirror of the workaround, in case it goes missing.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the `INDEX` function. To increase the confusion about this function, Microsoft chose to implement two different types of this function. We're going to use the "array"-variant. More info on this function [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/index-function-HP010342608.aspx). This function enables us to select a matrix (your Sheet 1) and choose a row or a column from it. The `INDEX` function returns a reference to that row or column. Next, we'll use `SUM` to add all items in the column. The final trick is to select the right column. To do that, we'll lookup the *row* number (using `ROW`) in Sheet 2 and use that to reference the right column in Sheet 1.

Now for the formula: put this in B2 (column A has the product names) `=SUM(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$DG;;9+ROW(Sheet2!A1)))' and copy-paste down as far as needed.

Two notes on the formula:

- there is no second argument in the `INDEX` function, making the function return *a reference* the entire column, which is then added (`SUM`);
- adding 9 tow `ROW` is needed because your product data starts in column J, the 10th column, so 9+1 = 10, the first column to be selected.

One final remark: to select an entire column, use the `J:J`-notation instead of `J1:J1048576` as suggested in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Am I implemening your answer correctly?  All I'm doing is copying your code: `=SUM(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$DG;;9+ROW(Sheet2!A1)))'` and putting that into cell A1 in sheet2 - and I'm getting an error (it auto-highlights `$DG`).

Comment: @Daniel: sorry, I should have mentioned where te put the formula. See the answer. Your products are in the A column. The formula should be placed in B1 and then copy-pasted down.

Comment: Thanks again for the response.  I'm still getting that error (that there's a typo or something).  I will clarify what I have one more time, in case its not clear. `Sheet1 J1:DG1` contains each item. `Sheet 1 J2:DG2` contains quantities for the item above it.  `Sheet2 A1:A102` contains the same as `Sheet1 J1:DG1`. I would like `Sheet2 B1:B102` to show the `SUM` of each item.  So `Sheet2 B1` should be the `SUM` of `Sheet1 J:J`, and `Sheet2 B2` should be the `SUM` of S`Sheet 1 K:K`.  Thanks again, really appreciate your help!

Also, shouldn't the `;` in your code, be a `,`?

Comment: I understand what you want to do. Please let me know the exact error that you get. You are using and English language version of Excel and your sheet 1 actually is called "Sheet1"? Instead of typing `Sheet1!$a:$DG` you can also select that part of the formula and with the mouse select sheet 1 columns A through DG (select by clicking and dragging the mouse over the column headers; see [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/select-cells-ranges-rows-or-columns-on-a-worksheet-HP010342878.aspx) for and explanation how to select multiple columns).

Comment: Thanks again for replying. Yes to all of the above.  The error I receive is the default error when entering an incorrect formula string.  I wish I understood more about your answer, as it seems it would be useful to know in the future.  In the meantime however, I found a workaround to my issue here: [link](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/transposing-cells-which-contains-formula-t2946068.html), 2nd post.  I **really** appreciate your help. I would post the Excel page for you to see, but it contains personal information.

Comment: @Daniel: please consider posting an answer to your question for future reference and marking your answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: Will do.  I tried upvoting your original answer, yet I do not have enough rep to do so.  Thank you for all your help.